# Syntax to use to call methods-on-pointers

Tags: go

Some questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433050/go-methods-sets-calling-method-for-pointer-type-t-with-receiver-t?rq=1) run into problem that in some cases calling:

```
obj.method()
```

Is invalid if `method` accepts pointer to object. But in some cases it is valid (like if `obj` is variable).

Question: should `(&obj).method()` always be used for consistency? Otherwise, code for calling same methods on same "type" is inconsistent depending on how `obj` was passed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should only reference or dereference the object when absolutely necessary. Go does this as needed when using [selectors](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors), and the method will be called with the proper receiver type regardless. If you write it otherwise, you're just going to confuse people trying to read your code.