# Pointer receiver and Value receiver difference in implementation with Iris framework

Tags: go

I am studying Iris framework recently. I encountered a question when I was implementing the Handler. Like following:

```golang
package controller

import "github.com/kataras/iris"    

type Pages struct{
}

func (p *Pages) Serve(c *iris.Context) {
}
```

In order to use this controller, I implemented the following entry script:

```golang
package main

import (
     "github.com/kataras/iris"
     "web/controller"
)

func main(){
      ctrl := controller.Pages{}
      iris.Handle("GET", "/", ctrl)
      iris.Listen(":8080")
}
```

But when I compiled the code, I got the following error message:

```
cannot use ctrl (type controllers.Pages) as type iris.Handler in argument to iris.Handle:
controllers.Pages does not implement iris.Handler (Serve method has pointer receiver)
```

After I changed the declaration to:

```
ctrl := &controller.Pages{}
```

Then the compiler passed with no complaint.

The question is: I thought the following statements are equal, since the GO compiler will do the conversion under the table:

```golang
type Pages struct {
}

func (p *Pages) goWithPointer() {
    fmt.Println("goWithPointer")
}

func (p Pages) goWithValue() {
    fmt.Println("goWithValue")
}

func main() {
    p1 := Pages{}
    p2 := &Pages{}

    p1.goWithPointer()
    p1.goWithValue()

    p2.goWithPointer()
    p2.goWithValue()
}
```

Why can't I use `ctrl := controller.Pages{}` as the parameter to `iris.Handle()`, instead of `ctrl := &controller.Pages{}` as the parameter to `iris.Handle()`?

Thank you for your time and sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See Docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type `T`
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set
>   of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of `T`). Further rules apply to structs containing anonymous fields,
>   as described in the section on struct types. Any other type has an
>   empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
>   non-blank method name.

And see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591156/6169399 :

> If you have an interface `I`, and some or all of the methods in `I`'s
>   method set are provided by methods with a receiver of `*T` (with the
>   remainder being provided by methods with a receiver of `T`), then `*T`
>   satisfies the interface `I`, but `T` doesn't. That is because `*T`'s method
>   set includes `T`'s, but not the other way around.

Using `ctrl := Pages{}` makes error:

```
cannot use ctrl (type Pages) as type Handler in argument to Handle:
Pages does not implement Handler (Serve method has pointer receiver)
```

Using `ctrl := Pages{}`needs:

```
func (p Pages) Serve() {
    fmt.Println(p.i)
}
```

[Iris Handler](https://godoc.org/github.com/kataras/iris#Handler) is an interface type. like this working sample (see comment):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Handler interface {
    Serve()
}

type Pages struct {
    i int
}

func (p *Pages) Serve() {
    fmt.Println(p.i)
}

func Handle(p Handler) {
    p.Serve()
}

func main() {
    // cannot use ctrl (type Pages) as type Handler in argument to Handle:
    // Pages does not implement Handler (Serve method has pointer receiver)
    //ctrl := Pages{}
    ctrl := &Pages{101}
    Handle(ctrl)
}
```

output:

```
101
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://godoc.org/github.com/kataras/iris#Handler. Iris Handler is an interface type.

GO performs implicit pointer-conversion on variables only, not on interfaces.