# Failed to implement Go interface because of pointer receiver

Tags: go

My `go test` can not be passed. What's wrong? What's the meaning of `(Handle method has pointer receiver)`

```
package ipc

import (
    "testing"
)

// import (
//  "encoding/json"
//  "fmt"
// )

type Request struct {
    Method string `json/"method"`
    Params string `json/"params"`
}

type Response struct {
    Code string `json/"code"`
    Body string `json/"body"`
}

type Server interface {
    Name() string
    Handle(method, params string) *Response
}

type IpcServer struct {
    Server
}

func NewIpcServer(server Server) *IpcServer {
    return &IpcServer{server}
}

type EchoServer struct {
}

func (server *EchoServer) Name() string {
    return "EchoServer"
}

func (server *EchoServer) Handle(method, params string) *Response {
    return &Response{"OK", "Echo " + method + " " + params}
}

func TestIpc(t *testing.T) {
    server := EchoServer{}

    ipcServer := NewIpcServer(server)
}
```

When I run `go test ipc_test.go`

```
/ipc_test.go:49: cannot use server (type EchoServer) as type Server in argument to NewIpcServer:
    EchoServer does not implement Server (Handle method has pointer receiver)
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You may use

```
server := &EchoServer{}
```

instead of

```
server := EchoServer{}
```

[Method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type `T`
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set
>   of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of `T`). Further rules apply to structs containing anonymous fields,
>   as described in the section on struct types. Any other type has an
>   empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
>   non-blank method name.

And see: [Pointer receiver and Value receiver difference in implementation with Iris framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987391/pointer-receiver-and-value-receiver-difference-in-implementation-with-iris-frame)

---

2- Or you may use

```
func (server EchoServer) Name() string {
    return "EchoServer"
}

func (server EchoServer) Handle(method, params string) *Response {
    return &Response{"OK", "Echo " + method + " " + params}
}
```

with

```
server := EchoServer{}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NewIpcServer` receives an interface which can be satisfied by a value-type or a pointer-type.

Since `EchoServer` implements the interface functions as pointer-type receiver (e.g `func (server *EchoServer) ...`) then you must pass a pointer to the `NewIpcServer` function.

In your `TestIpc` function change `server` to be a pointer as such

```
server := new(EchoServer)
```

and your test should compile just fine.