# About the interface assignment

Tags: pointers, go, methods, interface

Why doesn't Go think it's type mismatch error when a struct pointer be assigned to an interface?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type ABC interface {
    a() string
    b() int
}

type XYZ struct {
    aa string
    bb int
}

func (xyz XYZ) a() string {
    return "XYZ"
}

func (xyz XYZ) b() int {
    return 123
}

func main() {
    var xyz *XYZ
    var abc ABC = xyz // type of abc is *main.XYZ，I think that Golang can find this error here, but why not?

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", abc)

    a, ret := abc.(*XYZ)
    fmt.Println(a, ret) // type of a is *main.XYZ

    fmt.Println(a.a()) // will occur a error, because the type of a(*main.XYZ) not implements the interface ABC
}
```

I want know why Go doesn't think this is an error at "var abc ABC = xyz"

Comment: XYZ implements the interface ABC fine, so I think perhaps you misunderstood how Go interfaces work? If a struct has all the methods specified by the interface, it implements it without you having to do anything about that. And that is what you did, XYZ has all the methods specified by ABC, namely `a() string` and `b() int`.

Comment: thanks, and I defined the receiver of a() and b(), is XYZ, not is *XYZ.    XYZ.a() is ok, *XYZ.a() will not work. so, I think *XYZ not implements ABC.

Answer (score 1):

XYZ does implement ABC. This has to do with how [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) are determined (emphasis added):

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. *The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T* (that is, it also contains the method set of T).

[The method set determines whether an interface is implemented](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types):

> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to *implement the interface*.

When calling `*XYZ.a()`, the Go compiler can always automatically dereference the pointer to obtain a value receiver. There is no downside to doing so, because the receiver cannot be modified (as far as the caller is concerned).

The inverse is true if and only if the value is addressable:

```golang
type T struct {}
func (*T) M()

func main() {
    var t T
    t.M() // ok; t is addressable and the compiler rewrites this to (*t).M()

    var m map[string]T
    m["x"].M() // error: cannot take the address of m["x"]
}
```

See also: [Golang Method Sets (Pointer vs Value Receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587227/golang-method-sets-pointer-vs-value-receiver)

Answer (score 0):

> will occur a error, because the type of a(*main.XYZ) not implements the interface ABC

Wrong. `*main.XYZ` implements `ABC` (else `abc = xyz` would fail at compile-time, try to rename the method `b` to `c` for example), but the variable `a` holds a `nil` pointer (of type `*XYZ`). And since the `XYZ.a()` method has value receiver, to call that, a pointer value of type `*XYZ` would have to be dereferenced. But a `nil` pointer points to nothing, it cannot be dereferenced, an attempt to do so results in a runtime panic, just as you experienced.

If you would initialize `xyz` in the beginning with a non-`nil` pointer, it would work:

```
var xyz *XYZ = new(XYZ)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MUJ9F3uEvqB).

Also note that if `XYZ.a()` and `XYZ.b()` would have pointer receivers, then it would also work if `xyz` is `nil`:

```
func (xyz *XYZ) a() string {
    return "XYZ"
}

func (xyz *XYZ) b() int {
    return 123
}

func main() {
    var xyz *XYZ
    // ...
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nCLAx1e2taZ). The reason for this is because if the receivers are pointers, the `nil` pointer does not have to be dereferenced in order to call methods with pointer receivers, so no runtime panic occurs. Of course if in the methods you would refer to the `XZY.aa` or `XYZ.bb` fields, that would be a runtime panic, but your current method implementations does not do so, so it works.

Comment: thanks, Golang can invoke the method a() on a pointer to nil value(but the type is distinct,  XYZ),  it will transfer nil as a receiver to a(). so, Go should know *XYZ is not the receiver of a(), it can determine a() can not be invoked on *XYZ.

Comment: certainly, I have try like you do, before I ask the question,  just modify (xyz XYZ) a() => (xyz *XYZ) a() , it will work right, because the receiver is matched. I was thinking: Since Golang allow the situation，why not it occur error when I assign *XYZ to abc?

Comment: @JoeRadar It's not about matching. If methods have non-pointer receivers, then both `XYZ` and `*XYZ` types implement the interface. The problem is that a `nil` pointer cannot be dereferenced to call the non-pointer methods. If the pointer is initialized, it works with non-pointer methods too. It's all written in the answer.

Comment: maybe I understand all of what you said, but I think I can give a answer for the question. when I invoke a method of a struct that implem

Answer (score 0):

@icza, maybe I don't understand all of what you said, but I think I can give a answer for the question now. when I invoke a method on a value(not pointer, the method of a struct that implements a interface, and the receiver of the method is a pointer). the Golang will create a new object and copy value from the original struct value, then, the iface.data will point the new object, now ,when we pass the pointer of the new object to method, it will can be modify, but this operate will not change the origin struct value, this is not any useful, so, Golang will occur a error when we assign a struct value to a interface(pointer receiver)