# Pass pointer as an interface type to the function

Tags: go, pointers, interface

I am a new to Go and the behavior below confuses me:

```
package main

type Contractor struct{}

func (Contractor) doSomething() {}

type Puller interface {
    doSomething()
}

func process(p Puller) {
    //some code
}

func main() {
    t := Contractor{}
    process(&t) //why this line of code doesn't generate error
}
```

In Go some type and pointer to this time conform to the interface? So in my example **t** and **&t** are both *Puller*s?

Comment: Correct: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Answer (score 6):

From the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> A type may have a *method set* associated with it. The method set of an
> interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type `T`
> consists of all methods declared with receiver type `T`. The method set
> of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods
> declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method
> set of `T`).

In your case the method set of `&t` (which is of type `*Contractor`) is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*Contractor` or `Contractor`, so it contains the method `doSomething()`.

---

This is also discussed in the [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers), and in [Go code review comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type). Finally, this is covered by many past Stack Overflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775376/value-receiver-vs-pointer-receiver) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587227/method-sets-pointer-vs-value-receiver).