# In go, is it backwards compatible to change a receiver struct from a value to a pointer?

Tags: go, backwards-compatibility

Starting with code like:

```
type Foo struct {
    V bool
}

func (f Foo) bar() bool {
    return f.V
}
```

Is it allowed to change to `func (f *Foo) bar() bool` without incrementing the major version number? That is, assuming you know there are no thread safety issues with your type. If so, the reverse change is allowed too, correct?

Any code that called the function regardless of whether the variable was a value or a pointer would continue to compile and work as expected after both changes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587227/method-sets-pointer-vs-value-receiver) answer your question?. [Here](https://go.dev/play/p/QNnQ2Kgqy2C) is an example that breaks with the change.

Comment: Thanks! I think that does answer it, it is not compatible to make this change. I suppose point 4 in the answer to that question also means that it would change which type (pointer or value) satisfies any interfaces it has the methods for, so I suppose that makes the reverse change not compatible either if it satisfies any interfaces (and you can't guarantee it doesn't).

Comment: Fortunately I benchmarked it and it makes no difference in speed whether my type is a pointer or value anyway

Comment: @Brits could you add that an an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591156/11810946) answer provides a good summary `T` vs `*T` receiver types. Following are a couple of examples where a change from `func (f Foo) bar() bool` to `func (f *Foo) bar() bool` would break existing code.

Example 1: `T` is not addressable ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/QNnQ2Kgqy2C)):

```
type Foo struct {
    V bool
}

func (f *Foo) bar() bool { // Change to `(f Foo)` and this will work
    return f.V
}

func x() Foo {
    return Foo{true}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v", x().bar())
}
```

Example 2: Interface ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/YDZfra_ZuaG)):

```
type Foo struct {
    V bool
}

func (f *Foo) bar() bool { // Change to `(f Foo)` and this will work
    return f.V
}

type Fooer interface {
    bar() bool
}

func main() {
    var x Fooer
    x = Foo{}
    fmt.Println(x.bar())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If for a type `Foo` you have a method with value receiver:

```
func (f Foo) Method() {...}
```

Then this method is defined for both `Foo` and `*Foo`, and for both cases, the method receives a copy of the instance of `Foo`. If you change this to :

```
func (f *Foo) Method() {...}
```

then `Foo.Method` is only available for `*Foo`, and not for `Foo`. Thus, such a change may cause compile errors.

If you have a method declared with pointer receiver and now you change that to a value receiver, you declare the method for both `Foo` and `*Foo`, so you should not have compile errors. The semantics of the method will also change, because now `Method` will receive a copy of the instance of `Foo` even if that instance is addressable, or it is a pointer.

Comment: I tested it and it compiles to use a pointer variable with a value receiver: https://go.dev/play/p/pKwO7oA39w7

I thought it wouldn't work before I checked it too!